# Windows web server

Tags: windows-server-2003, hosted

I need a windows 2003 hosted server for various websites that I develop and host. Any suggestions on a good deal out there?

I need full root access to IIS 6/7 and to be able to host multiple websites using host headers.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[1and1](http://www.1and1.com) have good and affordable virtual and real servers.

Answer (score 0):

[SoftLayer](http://www.softlayer.com) has been good to me over the years.  I have dedicated servers in both their Dallas and Seattle facilities and have had nothing but great experience with their support staff when needed (had a hard drive failure once and it was replaced and back online within an hour).  They deploy the server and you get remote desktop access to the administrator account and can do whatever you like with the setup on the box.

Answer (score 0):

[seetech](http://www.seetech.com) have basic packages but can customise them based on your requirements. While you can not get direct access to IIS, you do have control panel access that allows for adding, removing domains and configuring them 24/7.